# Patents on similar items

Tags: discussion, prior-art, prior-art-request

I have been reading through some of the patents here that cover a similar idea I have for a product. There are variations. If I design an item that is more practical and cost effective than another is it still under the same patent or do I have a prior art issue?

I guess an example would be that someone patented a hydraulic device to pull a stump. This patent was very large and needed to be pulled around on a tractor trailer. The devise I have designed is smaller and works by a ratcheting lever. Is this the same patent?

Is this an acceptable question for this forum?

Comment: Hi, AskPatents is an online service in Q&A format where users help find **prior art** on **US Patent Applications** and US Patents and ask questions about the US Patent process. Moving this to [Ask Patents Meta](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com) as it is a question about which questions fall within the scope of Ask Patents. Please see [faq] for more information about which topics are on topic for AskPatents. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

To fit in our guidlines for an on-topic question you can re-word it slightly to be a question about how the US patent system works. For example "is a device that accomplishes the same end result as a previously known design and uses some common elements with past deigns (but does it in a different and improved manner) patentable?" " How would the patent office look at my device in comparing it with the most similar old solutions?"

I know that is not very different in substance from the original post but it is more clearly worded as a question about how the system works. N